# Using Boost::Asio for http client connection with my RestAPI server, things are good but somehow 1/20 times I hit with heap corruption

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, heap-corruption, boost-beast

Below is code snippet from the actual code base. Please assume host, port, ioc, all are available and initialized.

```
// Connection establisher class
class CSSLConn: public std::enable_shared_from_this<CSSLConn>
{
   :  
   : 
};

// Class for maintaining the thread pool
class CHttpClient
{
  // vector to hold connction objects
  std::vector <std::shared_ptr<CSSLConn>>   m_sslConnObj{};


// main method call this to create connection
void CHttpClient::Initialize(int nThreads)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < nThreadCount; ++x)
    {
        worker_threads_.create_thread(boost::bind(&CHttpClient::WorkerThread, this));
    }

    // let connection get established
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
}

// creating threads for thread pool
void CHttpClient::WorkerThread()
{
    auto client = std::make_shared<CSSLConn>(ioc, m_ctx, sHost, sPort);
    client->connect(sHost.c_str(), sPort.c_str());
    m_sslConnObj.push_back(client);
    ioc->run();  
}

};
```

1/20 times I hit with heap corruption while it try to create thread pool, mostly with the second thread. I am suspecting std::vector, because it allocate memory while pushing (but I am not sure is it the real culprit). I am maintaining the vector of connection to disconnect all at end.

sometimes crash happens at "boost::system::error_code background_getaddrinfo" function, but all the values looks good here.

I am not much familiar with boost, if anyone know how to debug it better, how can I see what is going inside Boost will help me a lot.

Comment: Run with valgrind, helgrind, ASAN, UBSAN, TSAN. You probably have data races. That's [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) 100% of the time, not just the cases where you see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I see multiple shared objects being accessed from multiple threads
   without any synchronization in place:

   ```
   void WorkerThread() {
       auto client = std::make_shared<CSSLConn>(ioc, m_ctx, sHost, sPort);
       client->connect(sHost.c_str(), sPort.c_str());
       m_sslConnObj.push_back(client);
       ioc->run();
   }
   ```

   Here `m_sslConnObj` is modified without any locking. So unless
   that's somehow a thread-safe container type, that's already
   [Undefined
   Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
2. The same goes for other things like `m_ctx`.
3. It is also a code-smell that you are posting async work from
   separate threads, ***as if that meant anything***. `io_context` is
   run from all the threads, so you might as well just run the threads
   and create all clients from the main thread. [They will still be
   serviced from all the worker threads](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html#boost_asio.overview.core.threads.thread_pools).
4. Just noticed, it's also weird that `CSSLConn` takes `sHost` and
   `sPort` as constructor parameters, but then when you call
   `connect()` on them you pass them /again/ (but differently).

Comment: I didn't completely understand the second part of your suggestion. First part I understood that may be instructions in WorkerThread should be synchronized. 
My requirement is create a pooI of threads which my main function can use to call RestAPI calls. So I created single io_context and created multiple threads under it.

Comment: From the provided link, what I understand we can use io_service with multiple threads, then that should not be the problem.

Comment: I made few suggestions. Here's a demo of what I think is "normal": http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fae24f56e915006 Note that ctx and m_sslConnObj are now modified only from the main thread.

Comment: @rahul `io_service` is by far not the only object you're using from those threads though.`My answer lists a few of them _explicitly_.

Comment: thanks for the sample code. I will go back and do the changes as you suggested. how can you write code so fast it took me ages to understand all this details (still got only a piece). Will let you know my results. Thanks again.

Comment: I have build on your sample what I need, could you please review it for me. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d1082bc02b77c24.  I really appreciate your time on this. Thanks.

Comment: Tip: do you know CodeReview.stackexchange.com? I still appreciate the link because I don't usually go there

Comment: I never used it. thanks for the suggestion.-- what is the correct way to post task to thread_pool.  

m_sslConnObj.front()->senddata(req);   // what is the correct way of posting to thread pool

Comment: I did notice the question in the comment. The question is onfusingly worded. You don't want to "post to the pool", you want to run on the connection's strand. Running on the pool is just as much "on another thread" as just running it on the main thread.

Comment: Mmm. Are you conflating the concepts of a "thread pool" and a connection pool? These are not the same. A connection pool could be seen as a task consumer as well. But if you want a connection pool, why not make it one directly. I'll complete review first before thinking more about the real question (see [XY Problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: Maybe in the meantime you can take some time to describe *what* you want to achieve (in functional terms) as opposed to *how* (the code you had). So that we don't waste too much time solving the wrong problems.

Comment: Is that mean, I can call 10 RestApi call parallelly in our case. By sending it to connection's strand. Sorry I got confused  here.

Comment: It's okay to get confused. Happens to me all the time. It's a key skill for programmers to recognize when there is a kind of confusion, then deconstruct it so that [simplicity emerges](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0Ak6xtVXno). And since on SO we help programmers where they get stuck, I consider it on topic :)

Comment: I want to push data to RestApi server from my C++ application. The important part is that data push would be infinite and need multiple connection with server so that application can push as fast and as much it can to the RestApi Server. Its like pushing thousands of timeseries data in 1 second. So I created HttpClient using boost and beast. And brought the thread_pool concept so that multiple thread can push. And unlike other RestApi client I don't want to close the connection after one call, I want to reuse the connection so that "Connection establishment" time can be saved.

Comment: Pushing thousands [records] of timeseries data per second to the same server **surely** is better served by a batching/bulk protocol (where you send batches of several hundreds instead of single units). Otherwise, I think the logical approach would be to use UDP. Also, a key insight is that you likely don't need many threads at all. You can easily multiplex many many (~10k) concurrent IO operations using a single thread.

Comment: So all in all, the essential requirement that is left is "connection pooling", so that the number of (re)connections is reduced. You will want to think carefully about parameters: how will requests be scheduled (you apparently just always chose `front()` which is no good), is the pool fixed-size,  what if a connection breaks (do you replace it? How?). **After** you decide on the goals, then you come up with the simplest design that matches it.

Comment: (Oh, essential choice: do you fire-and-forget or do you want to handle responses too? If so, how? Just accumulating statistics, or do you need to deliver a response back to the caller of ``SendRequest`? It seems to me that you're not interested in the results since you declared it `void SndRequest(....)`)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Batch processing is the best approach. So I am making batches of 5k timeseries in one go. That reduces my number of pushes to the client. I liked your idea of concurrent IO operations using a single thread, but don't know how to do that using boost or in C++. I will try to read about this more.

Comment: Yes. I am not interested in the result, because there would be no resending :).

Comment: ERm, there wasn't anything about resending. So, maybe clarify that when you describe the final goals :)

Comment: Re: "using a single thread, but don't know how to do that using boost" - You already have the code. `async_write` and `async_read` are _asynchronous_ operations. So if you scale down the thread pool to 1 thread, you can still have numerous connections.

Comment: how will requests be scheduled -- Because its a timeseries data that's why I am not thinking much about schedule it in correct order. Data should reach to Server in no time. Pool size is fixed - not more than 6. If send or read operation fails, I trigger reconnect because I was using different threads so I used boost::emplace and refresh the connection.

Comment: By scheduling I also mean: do you need/want fair distribution across connections (e.g. if you have different connections that may lead to a different endpoint in a cluster). I don't see what "because I was using different threads" has to do with it, maybe you mean the overhead of creating new connection is acceptable **because** other threads can continue working?

Comment: If I am reading you correctly. I just need to call async_write continuously as soon as its writing done. In sample code from "on_write" I can post another async_write.  Is this what you are saying concurrent IO operation.

Comment: Not really. I'll show later. Completing first pass review - but taking time to comment on some thorny details. Then it's time to make dinner, but I;ll be back.

Comment: No. All threads endpoint would be the same. The basic two reasons I choose thread_pool because of parallel operation to the same endpoint and if one connection got block with any reason at least others would be actively pushing to the server. But after talking to you I am feeling that single thread approach would also work for me...I need to see its performance though :)

Comment: Here's the first pass at review, mostly commenting on observations *before* I went into the design goals at all: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36b20c096e74d739) (too large to compile online). There's 17 SEHE review comments, of which 8 are FIXes, the rest notes.

Comment: (Note that "I choose thread_pool because of parallel operation to the same endpoint" is still quietly conflating thread pool and connection pool, but the rest of the comment indicates that you're seeing it now)

Comment: Thanks Sehe...I am going through your comments. Also trying to understand about your single thread approach... :)

Comment: With [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36b20c096e74d739) I am gettin exception at: 
template<class Allocator>
net::const_buffer
basic_fields<Allocator>::
value_type::
buffer() const
{
    return net::const_buffer{data(),
        static_cast<std::size_t>(off_) + len_ + 2};
}

Comment: Probably some kind of version difference. What version of boost?

Comment: I've thought long and hard about it, and I do not see a way to configure a useful 1-producer many connection scenario without a queue - requiring synchronization. In fact, your sample ends up using strands per connection so every connection is on a mutex. The best way - without extra information - I can think of is a lock-free queue that is consumed by multiple async IO chains (optionally on multiple threads). However this either restricts the actual messages or requires an extra level of indirection, putting handles to the actual message in the queue. You get it: that becomes complicated

Comment: So I would not invest that unless the performance actually requires it. From experience the profiler will probably point at a lot of other bottlenecks before that. (Eg. you had some liberal copying of  messages, and the fact that you're intending to use `string_body` is a sure sign that you're not optimizing allocations nor serializations).

Comment: Let me draw up a simpler - clean - example of what I think would work. Then you can measure and decide which parts require/merit tuning.

Comment: I am using 1.72.0. In my current implementation I uses a queue if strand is busy. Performance is important but not on the cost of high maintenance...:). A simple solution will also do if throughout is around 100 ops per second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230461/discussion-between-sehe-and-rahul).